# what are the best practices for LDA parameters?

Tags: hadoop, mahout, lda

I have many documents (let's sat 5000) and I would like to extract some topics from them using tha `cvb` (LDA) in Mahout. It has many different parameters, starting from the number of latent topics (-k), max number of iteration (maxIter), max number of iteration per document (-mipd), smoothing for doc topic (-a), smoothing for term topic (-e), seed (-seed). I know setting the parameteres depends on my application, but what are the best practices? e.g. it is recommended to set -s to k/50.

I'm particularly interested in -mipd, -maxIter, -e.

How about parameters that the `seqsparse` command takes?

Comment: Did you get any useful info on this? I am particularly interested in mipd ... What is it really used for?